Unit test IRequestClient timeout
How can I test what happens when I get a RequestTimeoutException, without having to wait until the actual timeout?
Simplified example, where I want to test that the return value is "timeout":
try
{
    var response = await _client.GetResponse<MyResponse>(new MyRequest());

    return response.Status;
}
catch (RequestTimeoutException)
{
    return "timeout";
}

I have used Quartz in other tests to advance time after something has been published or sent, but in this case execution waits until a response has been sent or a timeout occured.

Set the request timeout to a insignificantly low value?

I didn't think about controlling the timeout when registering the clients. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!
